# show json value in a label in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In Angular 6 I click on a date time picker and set a label to the selected value.

At the moment it is showing as `{ "_value": "2018-09-14T09:30:00.000Z" }`

How can I show only the value, 2018-09-14T09:30:00.000Z?

Here is the html

```
<dl-date-time-picker minuteStep="15" (change)="myDateChanged($event)"></dl-date-time-picker>
<label class="text-secondary">{{ myDate | json }}</label>
```

and the called code

```
   myDateChanged(val: string) {
    this.myDate = JSON.stringify(val);
  }
```

Comment: So two questions, why do you use  "JSON.stringify" in your myDateChanged function and why do you use the json pipe? I think if you remove JSON.stringify and the json pipe the value should be displayed properly

Comment: @tomichel, I think if the OP does that it will show as [object Object], at least that's what I get when trying it, still trying to get the value out though

Comment: @DarkW1nter ok, you got me curious and I build it myself. the quick solution I found was to change the function to `myDateChanged(val: any) {
    this.myDate = val._value;
  }` and remove all the json stuff and it showed the value properly

Comment: nice one, you should put that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Change the function to

```
    myDateChanged(val: any) {
     this.myDate = val._value;
    }
```

And remove the json pipe from the html and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

access the `myDate._value` property

```
<label class="text-secondary">{{ myDate._value }}</label>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I had tried that before and it still show the same as what I posted

Comment: probably have to parse it to string. use `this.myDate = JSON.parse(this.myDate)`

Comment: createa a stack blitz demo